# Power BI Oracle on prem gateway issue - Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: oracle, powerbi, dashboard, gateway, directquery

I have a Power BI dashboard which has direct queries to an Oracle database, where I import data using SQL queries. On my local pbix file everything is fine. When I publish it to my enterprise powerbi.com site and want to refresh the data, I get the following error:

```
{"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_ProviderDataAccessArgumentError","pbi.error":
{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_ProviderDataAccessArgumentError","parameters":{},"details":
[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Unable to 
find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed."}},
{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":
{"type":1,"value":"-2147024809"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing the issue?

I have trawled through the Power BI forums and there does not seem to be a definitive remedy.

I don't have such an issue using Tibco Spotfire, however we are being pushed to use Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around. It seems that after you create the Views in Oracle, in PowerBI, you should rather import (as selected below) than make a direct query. Just click the import option and find your table with the view you create in the following options.
[image]

I still see the same error if I want to manually fresh the data on the PowerBI app, but I can at least now see my dashboard working, with the tables and graphics fully visible.